# Is there a way to update cuda driver using conda on windows 10

Tags: cuda, conda

I want to use

```
conda install -c hcc cuda-driver
```

to update cuda but I'm on windows ten and this command is for linux.

Comment: Hi Jacqueline. AFAIK, CUDA drivers should be [obtained from NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx). Installing drivers on Windows requires elevated privileges and that's generally something that Conda packages avoid having to do. The Conda packages that use CUDA assume the user has the CUDA driver already installed.

Comment: That command you have found is specifically for the U Nebraska Holland Computing Centre channel for working with provisioning their supercomputer nodes with conda. In general, conda can't (and I would never recommend using it even if it could) install drivers

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to update cuda driver using conda on windows 10

No there is not. Not on any platform. What you found is specifically a channel for a super computing facility for their own needs and is not applicable.